# My Android Studio is not working (Once again)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been using Android Studio for a while now and working on a project which I frequently copy from Bit-bucket. One day when I opened Android Studio (working the other day) and I just get a billion errors. I have already tried changing my build tools version and getting the package for it. I also tried cleaning project. Every time I do so I get a error.

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'F:\Programing\AndroidDevelopment\SDK\build-tools\21.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name (at \u0027value\u0027 with value \u0027@integer/google_play_services_version\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"F:\Programing\AndroidDevelopment\Projects\NBHSApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":48,"startColumn":27,"startOffset":2064,"endColumn":64,"endOffset":2101}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

This is only for this project as when I make a new one it is fine.
This is stopping me from being able to work so any advise is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like Android Studio is working fine but there in an error in your AndroidManifest

Comment: @cyroxis I get errors in every file

Answer (score 1):

You dont have the "Google Play Services" SDK installed, so your Manifest is giving you errors.

To install the SDK, just do this: [(Full tutorial here)](http://www.thedevline.com/2014/03/install-google-play-services-sdk-in.html)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Thank You @Jonty Morris!
It appears you have solved my question

Answer (score 0):

Download "Google Play Services" from Sdk manager.

Comment: OP already got his issue solved from another answer so please expand your answer with further explanation if you can. Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30864228)